# Performance issues with new laptop

Tags: performance, hardware

I recently purchased a gaming laptop (Lenovo Ideapad Y700) with a quad-core 64-bit i5 6300HQ CPU (2.2-3.2 GHz, 6MB cache) with an integrated Intel HD Graphics 530 GPU, 8GB 2133MHz DDR4 RAM, and a discrete nVidia Geforce GTX 680M GPU with 4GB DDR5 VRAM.

But whenever I start blender it's ridiculously sluggish... both UI responsiveness and rotating the camera in the viewport (even though it's just a non-shaded cube). I've tried starting Blender by right-clicking it and picking "Run with graphics processor > nVidia high performance graphics", I've tried going to "Preference > System" and changing it from CPU to CUDA (GTX 680M), I've tried changing the draw to full, overlap, overlap flip, triple buffer, etc... but all to no avail.

Has anyone here had similar problems? If so, how did you overcome it?

And does anyone have any suggestions as to what to try next? All my drivers are up to date.

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the solution was to right-click the Blender shortcut and start the program with the integrated graphics (which still allows me to use the other GPU for CUDA).